# How to prepare an Ubuntu bootstrap for non-privileged systemd-nspawn?

Tags: 16.04, users, systemd

I created an Ubuntu 16.04 bootstrap (via `debootstrap`) to be run via `systemd-nspawn` (also on 16.04). When started by

```
# systemd-nspawn -D <mycontainer>
```

I get a fully functional, correctly working system.

I would like to drop its privileges via the `--private-users` option. The man page states that

> Note that user namespacing currently requires OS trees that are
>   prepared for the UID shift that is being applied: UIDs and GIDs used
>   for file ownership or in file ACL entries must be shifted to the
>   container UID base that is used during container runtime.

**How exactly should this be done, in relation with the `UID` range used by the container?**

As a side note, I noticed that 16.04 (which ships with `systemd` version  229) does not have some probably useful switches described in the [official doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html): `--private-users-chown`, `-U` and `--private-users=pick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved in version `230` - my existing containers were automatically moved into a non-privileged version after the upgrade.

Now the container processes, as seen from the host, run with an unprivileged user.